# jQuery beginner - need assistance with .each() in terms of looping through *selective* input fields

Tags: jquery, forms, loops, twitter-bootstrap-3, each

My experience lies mostly with backend coding, PHP mostly. I am having some trouble understanding how to properly loop through an array of input fields ids using jQuery. I have seen Previous Posts on Stackoverflow very similar to my own, but just different enough to cause myself some head ache. I am sure this will be a whiz for a seasoned jQuery coder.

Keep in mind that I am a relative beginner in terms of jQuery and JS. 
* I am familiar with validated.js and jquery.validate.js, I am trying to learn more about jQuery and not interested in additional plugins at this time.

**What I am trying to do:**
I am trying to take input fields from a sign up form and assign varying degrees of thresholds in terms of character length, as well as some other switch style tricks within the form fields. I am able to accomplish what I want with one field, however, I want to loop through these fields and dynamically grab ID's due to their placements within arrays.

So for example. I have my input fields along with "character length" span tag to hold the `.length()` values of each input as well as an error div I can push err statements into using `.text()` or `.html()`.

```
<h4>First name: <span id="ufnLenDis" class="lngthDisplay"><!--displays .length()--></span></h4>
<div id="err_usr_first_name"><!--displays errMSG--></div>
<div class="input-group col-sm-12">
  <input type="text" id="usr_first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
```

**(UPDATE:)** Using jQuery, I want to classify certain input fields `ID's` as variables or object arrays. Like validation thresholds. Several input fields may have a max of 1 and a limit of 60 characters, where others have max of 8 and limits of 30 characters. Specific restrictions and/rules for different functions and variable groups that apply to certain fields but not all. So I create a variable and add these like `id` fields to run through a loop.

Really the rules are ancillary but I wanted to outline my objective with regard to one of these functions.

So here is my desired output in a single form entry.
*I am using bootstrap and latest jquery plugins along with animated.css/js.
*Character input threshold = 2 - 60

1. Length is === 0 remove all "bootstrap" alerts and any input related output statements in all relative tags.
2. length is === 1

   - add bootstrap `alert alert-info` and remove all other alert related classes
   - output character length in span tag held within header tag of input div also add class to change color to correlate with alert proper alert color
   - output alert message in error div in proper alert config
3. Length is > 1 or < 59

   - Add `alert-success`, remove all other alert classes
   - Add and remove relative classes to and from the other relative tags.
   - inform customer they are about to reach the limit of the character threshold.
4. Length is === 59 - reset alerts from possible over count

   - Add `alert-success`, remove all other alert classes
   - Add and remove relative classes to and from the other relative tags.
5. Length is === 60

   - Add `alert-warning` classes and remove other alert classes from the tags
   - Add `animated shake` to bring attention to the field input.
   - Inform customer they have reached the limit of allowable characters in err field.
6. Length > 60

   - add attr.("disabled") and place alert-danger in all relative tags classes.

Here is a working jfiddle of what I want to do:

[Jfiddle of single input field working](https://jsfiddle.net/jy4yvers/8/)

Again, this is one single input field, I want to take some code like the following and loop it through .each() and use the key/value pairs to construct the validation of multiple form fields coming from the same form, but some fields will not be run through the function.

Here is a jfiddle of what I have tried with the `.each()` function.
[Multiple input entries not working](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb19rcxy/3/)

I am really just looking for some assistance with getting the jQuery loop properly constructed using a variable that identifies the ID's of the input fields I want to run through a particular function that adds specific thresholds.

My code is located in each jfiddle. The first Jfiddle link is the working example of the field as I want it to perform. The second is my attempt at looping the function to apply the rules to multiple ids coming from the form.

Here is the raw code with out CDN extensions.
The following code snipit is working for my needs with one single input field at a time. 
However anytime I try to add an .each loop using examples I have seen, it breaks my code. I tried adding the following line and using the key/value pairs as substitutions for any val() call outs within the function. `$.each([ "#usr_first_name", "#usr_last_name", "#usr_company_name", "usr_city_name"], function( index, value ) {`, then use the index/value pairs to construct the function by replacing any call outs for the values within each() function. See my linked "non-working" jfiddle for an example.

[**Non working example of multiple fields**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb19rcxy/3/)

[**working example of single field**](https://jsfiddle.net/jy4yvers/8/) (code below)

```
var input = $('#proper_config');
$('#lenDis').text(input.val().length);
input.bind('keydown, keyup', function(e) {
  var spart = input.val().split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < spart.length; i++) {
     var j = spart[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
     spart[i] = j + spart[i].substr(1);
  }
$(this).val(spart.join(" "));
$('#lenDis').html("Character count: " + input.val().length).addClass("danger").removeClass("warning success info");
if (input.val().length === 0) {
  input.removeClass("alert-info alert-success alert-warning alert-danger");
  $('#lenDis').removeClass().addClass("hidden");
  $('#err').empty();
} else if (input.val().length === 1) {
  input.addClass("alert alert-info");
  $('#lenDis').addClass("info").removeClass("danger success warning hidden");
  $('#submitBTN').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#err').empty().html("Input field must have 2 or more characters and no more than 60 characters.");
} else if (input.val().length >= 2 && input.val().length < 59) {
  input.removeClass("alert-info").addClass("alert alert-success");
  $('#lenDis').removeClass("danger info waring").addClass("success");
  $('#err').empty();
} else if (input.val().length === 59) {
  $('#lenDis').removeClass("warning info danger").addClass("success");
  input.removeClass("alert-warning alert-info alert-danger").addClass("alert alert-success");
  $('#submitBTN').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#err').empty();
} else if (input.val().length === 60) {
  $('#err').removeClass().html("<small>You have reached the max amount of characters allowed for this field!<small>");
  $('#lenDis').addClass("warning");
  input.removeClass("alert-info alert-success alert-danger").addClass("alert alert-warning");
  $('#submitBTN').removeAttr('disabled');
} else if (input.val().length > 60) {
  $('#err').removeClass().empty().addClass("danger").html("You have exceeded the amount of characters allowed for this field!.");
  input.removeClass("alert-info alert-success alert-warning").addClass("alert alert-danger");
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you're main objective is to determine if all `input` fields have certain values using `$.each`?

Comment: @eeya, thank you for the response. No, I am sorry I thought I was quite clear on that part. I only want **some** of the inputs to run through the loop. I would like to use a variable or object to identify the inputs I wish to affect. For example, if I have a variable that holds the first and last names along with the company name and city names `ids` `var value = ("#first_name", "#last_name", "#company", "#city"). Then I can use these variables to run through an .each() loop. That was my idea.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `$.each` only for your case?

Comment: @eeya no, not at all. If it can be achieved with for-loop or other means I am game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given in your code documented in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lb19rcxy/3/, You've called several DOM ID elements like this:

```
var valLenSixty = ("#usr_first_name", "#usr_last_name", "#usr_company_name", "#usr_city");
```

Thus, by the time you've attached / bind these elements by a certain event listener (e.g keyup and keydown), It cannot determine which DOM elements you've place it:

You can fix this issue by wrapping them in a single / double quotations like this:

```
var valLenSixty = $("#usr_first_name, #usr_last_name, #usr_company_name, #usr_city");
```

Now for your case in using `$.each`, I don't think it would be necessary to use this since you've already called them in your variable `valLenSixty` beforehand.

You can call each of their values by using `$(this).val()` inside your event handler like this:

```
valLenSixty.bind('keydown, keyup', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Then I notice you've assigned another variables:

```
var lenDis = ("#ufnLenDis", "#ulnLenDis", "#ucnLenDis", "#uccLenDis");
var errDis = ("#err_usr_first_name", "#err_usr_last_name",
```

You can also simplify this by placing another `attribute` (e.g `data_len_dis_id`) for your `input` as well:

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="usr_company_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" data_len_dis_id="ucnLenDis">
```

From which you can call them like this: `$(this).attr('data_len_dis_id');`

```
var valLenSixty = $("#usr_first_name, #usr_last_name, #usr_company_name, #usr_city");

valLenSixty.bind('keydown, keyup', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).val());
    var spart = $(this).val().split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < spart.length; i++) {
        var j = spart[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        spart[i] = j + spart[i].substr(1);
    }

    var sDataLenDisId = $(this).attr('data_len_dis_id'); // expected output: ucnLenDis
    var oSpanDisplay = $('.form_group').find('span#' + sDataLenDisId).html("Character count: " + $(this).val().length).addClass("danger").removeClass("warning success info");

    // Rest of your code
});
```

Here's a revised js code for further reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/L07mvLqz/

Hope this helps for your case.

Comment: you are awesome! This makes so much sense after seeing it. I am so very ignorant of jQuery and your logic with the attributes is +1. Thank you for that alone! Some great tricks I will take with me from your explanation! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Happy coding